# A* search algorithm determine loop variable when no path exists

Tags: java, algorithm, search

I´ m trying to implement the **A* search algorithm** in Java, and I have a question:

How many times I need to run a A* loop, until there is clearly no existing path?

For Example: If i have a for-loop; how long should "i" increase?

Comment: 42. `i` should always be less than or equal to 42.

Comment: Questions need to be far more specific if people are to offer help. You have provided so little information that your question really cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have explored all nodes that you can reach with A*, without finding your goal, then you can assume that there is no path.

Comment: So, practically if all existing nodes are added in a closelist, right?

Comment: You cannot be sure that A* will consider all nodes : if there is no path, some nodes won't be added in the closed list. You should better consider the open list : if it's empty and if you don't have find a path, then there is no path.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are thinking of A* the wrong way. 
You run it until there are no more nodes to search. If you havent reached your target by then there is no path.

Psuedo:

```
//Our list of still open nodes
List<Node> nodesToSearch = new List<Node>(); 
while (nodesToSearch.Count > 0)
{
   //SearchNode, if its our target we are done

   //Add reachable neighbours to the list of nodes to search. So next iteration we will continue on searching those
   //Remove current node.. since its searched
}
//If we end up here without a target there is no path. 
//That means we have searched all nodes and their neighbours etc etc etc. Without reaching the target.
```

Comment: Thank you two, this helps me to restructure my idea of the problem.